# Sending Mail using Postfix+Mailtrap with Laravel/Lumen in AWS EC2 - Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: php, email, laravel-5, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-18.04

So, I have read through several articles and tutorials, but I could not find the solution of my problem.

First of all, in local development environment I am successfully testing emails with `mailtrap.io` and `Lumen 5.7`

Here is my `.env` in local development environment :

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
MAIL_PASSWORD=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=hello@example.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="Example app"
```

It is working fine.

When I am trying to send emails on my `Amazon EC2 - Ubuntu 18.04` with Lumen, First, I have installed `postfix` and configured successfully and tested with `mailtrap.io`, it works fine with `mail` command from `mailutils`.

In this situation I have changed my `.env` configurations as follows :

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=localhost
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=hello@example.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="Example app"
```

**So basically I am trying to send emails in the following manner (From > To):**

`Lumen > Postfix > Mailtrap`

But it is not working ! I have checked `/var/log/mail.log` to check for errors, but logging doesn't even triggered. **Where am I doing wrong?**

Help from experts would be appreciated.

Comment: have you solved that? I have the same problem.

Comment: @MeysamMahmoodi Yes, I have solved that, currently I am using a live mail server with queue system in production, you should check on the outbound and inbound port in the ec2 security group.